# "TypeError: 'FormMeta' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

Here is my WTForm

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField, SelectMultipleField,HiddenField,validators
from wtforms.validators import Required, Email, EqualTo

class CreateCar(Form):
   id = HiddenField ('id')
   plaque_no = TextField('plaque_no', [Required(message='pn')])
   plaque_img = TextField('plaque_img', [Required(message='pi')])
```

And here is my Flask view:

```
def manage(task=None,id=None):
    form = CreateCar
    return render('MyHTML.html', form=form)
```

Whenever I try to iter over my form fields by this:

```
{% for item in form %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this Error:

```
TypeError: 'FormMeta' object is not iterable
```

What's wrong with my form?
Thanks

Comment: Does my solution work ?

Comment: Yes but this way : CreateCar(request.form)

Answer (score 7):

You simply miss the () on CreateCar.

```
def manage(task=None,id=None):
    form = CreateCar() #HERE
    return render('MyHTML.html', form=form)
```